# How to declare 'Promise' constructor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await, ecmascript-5

I have an old TypeScript project targeting ES5 and upgrading to anything newer, like ES2015 for instance,  is not an option due to number of factors. While trying to compile a code leveraging async/await I'm getting an error:

`TS2705 (TS) An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your`--lib`option.`

The error suggests there are 2 options to solve it and the one upgrading to ES2015 is not an option for me, therefore I would like to know how I can declare the 'Promise' constructor exactly.

I searched the forum and found number of similar questions but all recommendations I was able to find ended up suggesting to upgrade to at least ES2015, which, as I pointed out above, is not an option in my case.

Comment: can u share the code where you are getting this issue ?

Comment: If you can't upgrade to ES2015 then why are you using async/await?

Comment: Have you tried looking for a polyfill?

Answer (score 1):

try to find the source code of Promise class in js and inject in into `global.Promise = 'what you copied'`

or you can use some other libraries like bluebird - the same way.

```
global.Promies = require('bluebird')()
```